# Merge objects in array with similar key

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects:

```
objArray = [
    {x: 1, y: 7},
    {x: 2, y: 14},
    {x: 1, z: 9},
    {x: 2, z: 18}
    {x: 1, n: 6}
    {x: 2, n: 16}
]
```

Is there an efficient way to merge for "X" without a for loop? so that I end up with:

```
objArray = [
    {x: 1, y: 7, z: 9, n: 6},
    {x: 2, y: 14, z: 18, n: 16}
]
```

So look for common `objArray[n]["x"]` and merge all hits into one object? It's OK to modify the original array or create a new one.

I'm aware this can be done with a loop, but I'm trying to avoid too many loops for this implementation, though I'm not sure if a reduce or a filter would work for this.

Comment: What if the `y` value is the same in two different objects?

Comment: Should have specified that. It never will be for this use case. Only "X" will be the same.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to avoid using a loop? Loops generally have better performance than the iteration methods from `Array.prototype`. The latter make for a more readable code, and performance is not an issue on small data samples, but for large data samples, a `for` loop performs significantly better.

Comment: I thought the opposite was true! I'm mainly looking for this to be fast, as the object arrays can be 700+ long, or even more. I was under the impression the array methods were actually faster!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and group by property `x`.

```js
var array = [{ x: 1, y: 7 }, { x: 2, y: 14 }, { x: 1, z: 9 }, { x: 2, z: 18 }, { x: 1, n: 6 }, { x: 2, n: 16 }],
    result = Array.from(
        array
            .reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.x, Object.assign({}, m.get(o.x), o)), new Map)
            .values()
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

You could use `reduce` method to build an object and then `Object.values` to get an array.

```js
const data = [{"x":1,"y":7},{"x":2,"y":14},{"x":1,"z":9},{"x":2,"z":18},{"x":1,"n":6},{"x":2,"n":16}]
const res = data.reduce((r, {x, ...rest}) => {
  if(!r[x]) r[x] = {x, ...rest}
  else Object.assign(r[x], rest);
  return r;
}, {})

const result = Object.values(res);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const objArray = [
    {x: 1, y: 7},
    {x: 2, y: 14},
    {x: 1, z: 9},
    {x: 2, z: 18},
    {x: 1, n: 6},
    {x: 2, n: 16},
]

const result = Object.values( objArray.reduce( 
  (p,c) => (p[c.x] = Object.assign( {}, p[c.x], c ), p ), {}
) );

console.log( result );
```